# Can't Deploy Simplest ASP.NET Core Web App to Azure VM

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-virtual-machine

I'm trying to deploy the simplest ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web App (Razor or MVC) I can imagine from Visual Studio 2017 15.8.2
and still failing.

I followed the instructions in 
https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/blob/AspNetVMs/docs/create-asp-net-vm-with-webdeploy.md
step by step

finished creating VM

checked the web management service is up and running

installed Web Deploy 3.6 as described above tutorial

installed Windows features required - ASP.NET 4.6

Port 80 (http) and 8172 (WebDeploy) is open 
checked the inbound rules in Azure portal 
and Windows Firewall in Remote Desktop

But WebDeploy still fails.

I used the credentials when I log on to the VM using RDP

It says

```
ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC
```

but I checked the web management service is running

Also, when trying to configure deploy profile, 'Validate Connection' fails without any error message.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

When installing Web Deploy 3.6, choose custom and select all checkboxes.

'Typical' setup does't work.

End up with "500 - Internal server error", but hey, 
at least file uploading works, and that's a huge step for MSFT, huh?

EDIT: When Web Deploy 3.6 was installed with 'typcial', the web management service was not running and set 'manual' so I turned it on and set the startup type 'automatic' in [services] but the problem continued. So I changed the Web Deploy setup to custom/select all and succeeded uploading.